# dynamic share posts to google plus page using rss feed

Tags: dynamic, rss, share, google-plus, feed

`Is it possible to dynamically share posts or links to google plus page using rss feed?`

`I can automatically share links to my Twitter page or my Facebook page using any Rss Feed`, but I can't find any similar application or tool to send my site posts to my google + page automatically

I hope someone can help me find a tool or give me a hint to develop an application can do that task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the [third-party tools](http://www.google.com/+/business/3rdpartytools.html) *might* enable you to do this for your Google+ Page (not for an individual), such as HootSuite as [this Video seems to suggest](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78jvpAQbGyc). However, you should be careful to follow the [Google+ user content and conduct policy](http://www.google.com/+/policy/content.html) and to make quality posts to avoid having your content becoming classified as spam.

There is no API that is available to the public that will allow your own app to publish content for a profile.

Comment: @ BrettJ It didn't grab old Rss Feed it only grab new feeds, is it right? or I can do other setting?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but that would be my assumption (getting new stuff only).